# Python/Pyqt expected string or Unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, pyqt4

> TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, QString found

I tried also `face_img` without `0` but is the same result. I tried to declare upfron like this `face_img=[]` but still the same error.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `get_images` is calling some kind of dialog that returns a `QString`. If you convert it to a `str`, you should be fine, e.g

```
cv2.imwrite(folder +'/' + str(counter) +'.jpg',str(face_img[0]))
```